# Could someone create a `software recommendation` tag?

Tags: support, status-completed, tags

DevOps is about culture but is also about tools , I think this site needs to contains questions like **"What devOps tools are available for ... "**.
[Exemple from AskUbuntu.com](https://askubuntu.com/questions/65083/what-kinds-of-desktop-environments-and-shells-are-available)

A <kbd>software recommendation</kbd> tag or <kbd>tool recommendation</kbd> tag is much appreciated, I don't have required privilege to add it.

Comment: I'm on the fence about this as there's already a software recommendation SE site. I'm not sure endless lists will be useful. If you have a specific problem ask how to tackle this problem, the tools will be named when necessary.

Comment: It's more like a wiki page .. to show a comparison between tools, I'm aware of software recommendation SE but I think devOps tools recommandation should be in the DevOps SE too.

Comment: [related](https://devops.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/79/are-devops-related-sw-recommendations-on-topic-or-not) (nearly duplicate in fact)

Comment: @storm: [You currently have the reputation needed to create tags](https://devops.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/107/could-someone-create-a-docker-compose-tag)—you only need 150 rep.

Comment: @Aurora0001 :  Thanks , at least I learned something new :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Done](https://devops.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/software-recommendation) by following Shog9's advice from the question [Are DevOps related SW recommendations on-topic (or not)?](https://devops.meta.stackexchange.com/a/87/13) to allow them for now.